SharePoint framework for list viewing / editing
I'm looking to build a SharePoint online page that can point to a separate list and give the user the possibility to search, view and update list items within its own UI.
Is there a prebuilt template available or will I need to try to create something?
I am new to the development realm. Thank you for any help received.

Try leveraging list view control from @pnp/spfx-controls which is similar to SharePoint UI.
https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/ListView/

You will have to develop SharePoint Framework (SPFx) "web part" for your requirements in SharePoint Online.
Check below Microsoft official documentations to get started with SPFx development:

Overview of the SharePoint Framework
Build your first SharePoint client-side web part

For SPFx web parts with listing:
There is a free GitHub repository available for SPFx web part samples where you can find lot of SPFx samples which might help you. You can get code & inspiration from any available sample which will be similar to your requirements.
For example:
Sales Orders Web Part:

DataTable Using MUI table:

You can find all SPFx samples below:

SPFx web part samples

